# Magento local.xml reference name="head" to addItem from root

Tags: css, magento, local

I need to be able to call different CSS files in my local.xml within the reference name="head" to addItem with a full path from root (not from theme folder).

Right now I have 
skin_csscss/skin.css

And that will be http://www.domain.com/skin/theme_name/css/skin.css

I need to be able to point to http://www.domain.com/skin/OTHER-theme_name/css/skin.css

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>http://www.domain.com/skin/OTHER-theme_name/css/skin.css</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

The second param to `addLinkRel` is your magic sauce. Checkout the block object located at app/code/core/Mage/Page/Html/Head.php for more details.

Comment: That worked to call the file, but it did not add it to the (Merge CSS Files). Any suggestion to make it do that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get this to merge with the skin_css (at least not without some extra coding).

Comment: Actually, after looking at Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head, there are a few functions that might lead you to the right place to implement the merge. See `getCssJsHtml`, `_prepareStaticAndSkinElements`, and `_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements`.